# How to track linux kernel configuration changes?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, config, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I am working on a linux kernel module and would like to track my kernel
configuration changes (eg. enabling other modules, activating dynamic debug, etc.) for future reference.

`git add .config` doesn't feel right.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `.config` under Git is bad idea, as you correctly mentioned (basically because it's gone after `make distclean`, so this solution is not productizable). Also, if you already have `defconfig` file for your board, you shouldn't create another one, it may be considered as bad practice.

Instead take a look at [scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh) script. You can create your own config file which would contain only changes over some existing defconfig file, and then merge this file of yours with some basic `defconfig` file you are using.

Look at [TI kernel branch](http://git.omapzoom.org/?p=kernel/omap.git;a=blob;f=ti_config_fragments/android_config.sh;h=ad0ab7bfa1e98a934c6b405abf4f048144398cef;hb=refs/heads/p-ti-linux-3.14.y) for example, they are just creating another directory (`ti_config_fragments/`) with config chunks and scripts to generate final `.config` file.

Another way to use `merge_config.sh` script is to modify `Makefile` for your architecture, adding some new rule to merge your config fragment to already existing `.config` file, like it's done for `kvmconfig` rule in [arch/x86/Makefile](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/Makefile?v=3.17#L257).

Anyway, the main idea is to keep your config delta in separate file (somewhere in `arch/.../configs/` or in entirely new directory) and then merge your config fragment with existing `.config` file (which is usually generated from some `defconfig` file). And of course you can track your config fragment file under Git.

Comment: First of all any operations with *.config* is a bad idea. Since a good practice is to develop in own branch the developer may keep changes to any existing *defconfig* as a(set of) patch(es). We are doing like this in our team for internally shared repositories. As an example you may look at https://github.com/andy-shev/linux/commits/eds

Comment: Yeah, but what if you want to send your changes to upstream? Messing with existing `defconfig` file is not productizable neither. So why not stick to some little tiny delta config file ("fragment"), using `merge_config.sh` to merge it with original `defconfig` file instead (in order to produce final `.config`)?

Comment: The only need to send to upstream is when you adding a new board support, right? The best in that case either do in the way it's already done there: either portion of configuration ("delta" in your terms) or entire *defconfig*. Any other use cases I missed?

Comment: Your board can be intended to run both Android and GNU/Linux rootfs, which requires 2 different defconfig files. Logical solution is to have one defconfig and 2 different fragments (for Android and GNU/Linux). Also, you might want to run debug configuration for your board, it's another fragment. It would be inconvenient to keep 3 different defconfigs for such cases, as they would be almost the same. Look [here](http://git.omapzoom.org/?p=kernel/omap.git;a=tree;f=ti_config_fragments;hb=refs/heads/p-ti-linux-3.14.y) for example. This is exactly the case for the author of question.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Add new defconfig for your board(hardware).

PATH: arch/arm/configs/ for ARM architecture.

You can add new one via **make menuconfig** -> **Save**. To apply your own config just run `make your_board_defconfig`